# OnLoadFinished not received from LoaderManager when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-loadermanager

I have an activity with a ListView and the data for the ListView is loaded using Loaders.

I want to refresh the data whenever onResume is called so I am calling LoaderManager.initLoader(..) in onResume()

The problem is that when orientation changes (to landscape from portrait) I don't get a callback on onLoadFinished and so my UI doesn't get updated.

The funny part is that when the orientation is changed back to portrait mode it works fine.

Digging a little deeper, I found that if I merely call getLoaderManager() in onCreate() it solves the problem. But this dosen't seem right.

Can someone explain what happens when you change orientation? Has anyone faced this before?

Code snippet ->
http://pastebin.com/86R1ib06

Comment: Try using loadermanager.restartloader()

Comment: I am already doing loadermanager.restartloader()